# regex not producing the desired indentation - Perl

Tags: regex, perl

I have the following `Perl` script with is meant to indent a `XML` file correctly:

```
@files = glob "*.xml";

undef $/;
for $file (@files) {
    $indent = 0;
    open FILE, $file or die "Couldn't open $file for reading: $!";
    $_ = readline *FILE;
    close FILE or die "Couldn't close $file: $!";

    # Remove whitespace between > and < if that is the only thing separating them
    s/(?<=>)\s+(?=<)//g;

    # Indent
    s{  # Capture a tag <$1$2$3>,
        # a potential closing slash $1
        # the contents $2
        # a potential closing slash $3
        <(/?)([^/>]+)(/?)> 

        # Optional white space
        \s*

        # Optional tag.
        # $4 contains either undef, "<" or "</"
        (?=(</?))?
    }
    {
        # Adjust the indentation level.
        # $3: A <foo/> tag. No alteration to indentation.
        # $1: A closing </foo> tag. Drop one indentation level
        # else: An opening <foo> tag. Increase one indentation level
        $indent +=
            $3 ?  0 :
            $1 ? -1 :
                  1;

        # Put the captured tag back into place
        "<$1$2$3>" .
        # Two closing tags in a row. Add a newline and indent the next line
    ($1 and defined($4) and ($4 eq "</") ? "\n" . ("  " x $indent) : 
$4                                   ? "\n" . ("  " x $indent) :
                                       ""
        )
    # /g repeat as necessary
    # /e Execute the block of perl code to create replacement text
    # /x Allow whitespace and comments in the regex
    }gex;

    open FILE, ">", $file or die "Couldn't open $file for writing: $!";
    print FILE or die "Couldn't write to $file: $!";
    close FILE or die "Couldn't close $file: $!";
}
```

First, it's indenting my `tabs`, and I wanted **two whitespaces**. Also, it's producing tags in the same indentation to be on the same line, instead of in the next line, but with the same indent:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?><!DOCTYPE kit SYSTEM "tc.dtd"><kit><contact/><description>
```

where it is supposed to be:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
  <!DOCTYPE kit SYSTEM "tc.dtd">
  <kit>
      <contact/>
      <description>
```

...

I acknowledge there are Perl tools to indent `XML`, such as `XML-Tidy` but due to `tc.dtd` tag, I always get an error complaining about unsolvable dependencies on the `tc.dtd` file, while I just care about the indentation of the same (formatting), not the dependencies itself.
What's wrong with my `Perl` regex?

Comment: you should use an xml parser instead of regex to do this kind of thing

Comment: Why not using an xml indenter? I usually go with visual studio, but I think you can find a lot of those on the web. I just tried with visual studio, it complained a bit but indented correctly your code.

Comment: you can also try `xml_pp` which comes with XML::Twig

Comment: @mirod  Do you have more details ?

Comment: see https://metacpan.org/module/xml_pp XML::Twig is available for Activestate Perl (see http://code.activestate.com/ppm/XML-Twig/ ) and should install without any problem on Strawberry Perl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the tool [xmllint](http://xmlsoft.org/xmllint.html) which doesn't necessarily validate. Example:

Input (badly formatted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?> <!DOCTYPE kit SYSTEM "tc.dtd"> <kit>
  <contact/>      <description>chunky bacon</description> </kit>
```

Run `xmllint --format file.xml` and you get:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE kit SYSTEM "tc.dtd">
<kit>
  <contact/>
  <description>chunky bacon</description>
</kit>
```

Comment: and if I'm in Windows 7 computer?

Comment: There are Windows binaries available, see http://www.zlatkovic.com/libxml.en.html for download location and installation instructions.

Comment: If you have visual studio open it, open the file, press Ctrl+E Ctrl+F and you have your indentation

Answer (score 2):

You must *always* `use strict` and `use warnings` at the top of *every* program. This applies especially if you are asking for help with your code, as these measures can catch simple errors that would otherwise be overlooked

Please also use lexical file handles, and you have *way* too much commenting for your code to be clear

Your code is probably failing because it takes no account of how deeply the tags are *already* indented: it simply adds space before any two consecutive tags. Note particularly that `"  " x -1` doesn't work, and that elements with PCDATA (text) content are simply ignored and left at their current indentation

Formatting XML isn't as simple as you wish it was. You should take everybody's advice and use an existing module to format your data. Both [`XML::LibXML`](https://metacpan.org/module/XML%3a%3aLibXML) and [`XML::Twig`](https://metacpan.org/module/XML%3a%3aTwig) have formatting options. Yes, they will need access to the corresponding DTD but that is a *good* thing